# What are possible reasons that validation error doesn't change but train loss decreases?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I use pre-trained ResNet to extract 1000 dimensional features for each image, then put these images into my self-built net to do classification tasks and use triplet loss function.

There is a part of my code:

```
class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_feature = 1000, n_hidden_1 = 200, n_hidden_2 = 100, n_hidden_3 = 50, n_hidden_4 = 20,n_output = 3):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.net = torch.nn.Sequential(    
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden_1),
                        torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden_1),
                        torch.nn.ReLU(),
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2),
                        torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden_2),
                        torch.nn.ReLU(),
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3),
                        torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden_3),
                        torch.nn.ReLU(),
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4),
                        torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden_4),
                        torch.nn.ReLU(),
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_4, n_output),
                        torch.nn.Sigmoid()
                                )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.net(x)
        return x
```

and there are training and validation process:

```
    for epoch in tqdm(range(n_epoch)):
        model.train()
        for step, (batch_anchor, batch_positive, batch_negative )in enumerate(train_loader):

            anchor_out = model(batch_anchor)
            positive_out = model(batch_positive)
            negative_out = model(batch_negative)

            loss = loss_func(anchor_out, positive_out, negative_out)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        model.eval()
        for step, (batch_anchor_val, batch_positive_val, batch_negative_val) in enumerate(val_loader):

            anchor_out_val = model(batch_anchor_val)
            positive_out_val = model(batch_positive_val)
            negative_out_val = model(batch_negative_val)

            loss_val = loss_func(anchor_out_val, positive_out_val, negative_out_val)
```

where I define loss function and optimiser like following:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.002)
loss_func = torch.nn.TripletMarginLoss(p=2, margin=1)
```

and some results:

```
Epoch: 1/50 - Loss: 0.8764 - Val_loss: 0.9920
Epoch: 2/50 - Loss: 0.7035 - Val_loss: 0.9897
Epoch: 3/50 - Loss: 0.6313 - Val_loss: 0.9972
Epoch: 4/50 - Loss: 0.5958 - Val_loss: 0.9980
Epoch: 5/50 - Loss: 0.5724 - Val_loss: 0.9930
Epoch: 6/50 - Loss: 0.5541 - Val_loss: 1.0123
...
```

While training, train loss always decrease, but val loss doesn't change, I don't know why, maybe someone know what are potential reasons? I have read some blogs, and check my data set, I am sure my data set are correctly split.

Comment: how many data for training/val?

Comment: train with 40000, val with 10000

Answer (score 0):

Seems your model is not able to generalise to val set. Which means the model is unable to find the differences between (anchor, positive) vs (anchor, negative). In such case, distance of (anchor, positive) - distance of (anchor, negative) ~= 0. And since your margin is set to be 1. The **loss will stay at 1**. Recall the loss function definition from [TripletMarginLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.TripletMarginLoss.html).

I would suggest removing the `sigmoid` activation from last layer, and replace `relu` with `LeakyRelu` to improve the model's robustness.

Comment: I also try to change the activation function and remove sigmoid function, but it has a worse performance